# Equilibrium of the following system of non linear ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

How would find the equilibriums of the following system:

$$
\frac{d I}{dt}=-\frac{\beta S I}{N}   \qquad (1)$$

$$\frac{d S}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I   \qquad (2)$$

$$\frac{d R}{dt}=\gamma I   \qquad (3)
$$

where $S+I+R=N$ and $\beta,\gamma >0$.

I know one such equilibrium is
\begin{align}
e_1 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*, R_1^*\right)&= \left(N, 0, 0\right), \\[2ex]
\end{align}

How do I find the other(if it exists)? I believe it should be similar to the problem below unless I'm mistaken.

I have solved the more complicated case:

$$
\frac{d S}{dt}=\mu N -\frac{\beta S I}{N} - \nu S  \qquad (1)$$

$$\frac{d I}{dt}=\frac{\beta S I}{N} -\gamma I - \nu I  \qquad (2)$$

$$\frac{d R}{dt}=\gamma I - \nu R  \qquad (3)
$$

where $S+I+R=N$, $\quad$ $\mu =\nu$, $\quad$ $\mu, \beta, \nu,\gamma >0$.

Solutions are:

\begin{align}
e_1 : \left( S_1^*, I_1^*, R_1^*\right)&= \left(N, 0, 0\right), \\[2ex]
e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*, R_2^*\right)&= \left(\frac{N\left(\gamma+\nu\right)}{\beta}, N\nu\left(\frac{1}{\gamma +\nu}-\frac{1}{\beta}\right), N\gamma\left(\frac{1}{\gamma +\nu}-\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\right) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that a necessary condition for an equilibrium is given by:
$$\frac{dR}{dt} = 0 \implies I = 0.$$
Since the condition $I=0$ is enough to have $\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{dS}{dt} = 0$, you have a sufficient condition. Thus the equilibriums are given by:
$$(S^*,I^*,R^*) = (K, 0, N-K),$$
for any $0\leq K \leq N$.

Comment: Mhm, I was being stupid again. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Hmm technically your solution is correct however since this is an epidemic model, we cant have zero infected individuals with positive recovered individuals simultaneously because this would be nonsensical. So I believe the only equilibrium is the disease-free one.

Comment: @Math Why not? If your epidemic vanishes, i.e. $I(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, but $I(t_0)>0$ you would then have had a nonzero recovered population.

Comment: because $I=0$ implies $R=0$